# Solve the Equation:

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, systems-of-equations

The equation is: **$$x^{xn} = n $$**
I continued by taking logarithm on both sides but end up with an equation of the form: transcendental=rational, which I was unable to solve!!

Comment: Why transcendental? Can't $x$ have integer value? Or $x^x$ have integer value without $x$ being a rational anyway?

Comment: Note that your equation is equivalent to $x^x =n^{n^{-1}}$. (Assuming that $n$ is a positive integer). Can you find one solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve for $x$ I began by raising both sites to $\frac{1}{n}$-th power:
$$x^x=n^\frac{1}{n}$$
Taking log on both sides gives:
$$x\ln(x)=\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)$$
Now let $u=\ln(x), \ x=e^u \ $
$$e^u u=\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)$$
From the definition of Lambert W function
$$u=\text{W}(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n))$$
Resubstituting gives:
$$\ln(x)=\text{W}(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n))$$
$$x=\exp(\text{W}(\frac{1}{n}\ln(n)))$$
Which is solution to your equation. I hope that I've done everything properly.

Comment: Thank You, very much!